# Large front end file uploads on cloud

Tags: uploads, front-end

I need to setup a front end page to permits users not registered to send me big files (500mb).
I would prefer to host theese files in the cloud and not on my webserver.

I thought the best solution was dropbox with the dropbox uploader form, but it is limited to 300mb per file.

There are any file upload services that doesn't have this limitation?

Comment: At moment your question is about cloud services and WordPress. It would make sense to ask about WordPress integration after you have chosen service that fits your requirements. PS there is always FTP :)

Comment: The question is exactly which service can do what I need.. because I can't find neither one on google :-)

Comment: And it has nothing to do with WordPress. Consider asking on more fitting site of Stack Exchange network.